# How to create a dict that contains Java Classes hierarchy (in Python)?

Tags: java, python

I'm creating a class diagram drawer for Java and I need to look into standard Java Classes to check whether two classes have common ancestor (some additional feature). I was thinking of creating a dict that will contain class hierarchy, but I have no idea how to create it. The first thing I found is to create it from text file, that will use information from there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html. But I don't think it's the best solution. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jython for these purposes.

Start jython with jar-file or classes-folder in your 
classpath.

And do the next:

```python
#    import your java package by this way
import com.yourcomp.yourpackage as yourpackage 

#   gets superclass
def get_ancestor_4_class( c ):
    if not c or not c.__bases__: return java.lang.Object
    return c.__bases__[0].__name__

#   there all class to ancestor
#   mapping will be placed        
class2ancestor = {}

#   list (generator) of all classes in yourpackage 
yourclasses = (eval('yourpackage.%s' % classname) \
    for classname in dir( yourpackage ))

#    showtime!
for c in yourclasses:
    class2ancestor[ c.__name__ ] = get_ancestor_4_class( c ).__name__
```

All results U need in `class2ancestor`.